# Use Foundation's Measurement API to Perform Custom Unit Conversion

Tags: swift

I have three units of measurement that I need to convert between, and two of them are not provided by `Foundation`. One of the units, which is provided by `Foundation` is `UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion`. The other two units are `.millequivalentsPerLiter` and `degreesOfCarbonateHardness`.

The math that I need to use follows:

**1 meq/L = 2.8 dKH = 50 ppm**

I have tried to subclass `Foundation.UnitConverter`, but I don't understand how to use `baseUnitValue(fromValue value: Double) -> Double` and `value(fromBaseUnitValue baseUnitValue: Double) -> Double` to create the correct results.

Do I need to subclass `Foundation.UnitConverter` or `Foundation.UnitConverterLinear`? Do I need to create a subclass of `UnitConverter` for the conversion between each unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, you don't subclass UnitConverter. Instead you make concrete instances of UnitConverterLinear. For example:

```
extension UnitDispersion {
    static let millequivalentsPerLiter =
        UnitDispersion(symbol: "meq/L",
                       converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 50))
}

let value = Measurement(value: 1, 
                        unit: UnitDispersion.millequivalentsPerLiter) // 1.0 meq/L
value.converted(to: .partsPerMillion) // 50.0 ppm
```